# No overload for method 'Get sTring' takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net

I have a button code that passes data from a connectionString to a listBoxDat:

```
private void btnClick_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tbTitle.Text = "ADO.Net";
        listBoxData.Background = Brushes.LemonChiffon;

        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["crams"].ConnectionString;
        List<string> titles = new List<string>();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select filenum FROM dbo.Complaint";
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                titles.Add(reader.GetString());
            }
            listBoxData.ItemsSource = titles;
        }


    }
```

My error list keeps saying that there is No overload for method 'Get sTring' takes 0 arguments. I am not sure what this means!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SqlDataReader.GetString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx) methods expects an `int` parameter for index, specify `0` in your case sine your are only selecting a single field.

```
titles.Add(reader.GetString(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

The line of code:

reader.GetString()

must supply the index of the column for which you want to retrieve data from.

reader.GetString(0)

For column 0.